# Discord.py | How to add custom role per guild

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on event by name on_member_join and I want to give new ones a role, role for each guild isn't the same, so I need guild id for that. I have a json file where I've my guild id and role id for "auto role". I have an error inside `role = roles[str(member.guild.id)]`

> ERROR IS:
> await member.add_roles( role )   File
> "C:\Users\arman\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py",
> line 641, in add_roles
> await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason) AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'

MY JSON FILE ex:

> {
> "724249401962397767": "724868027241463859"
> }

```
#Auto role
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join( self, member ):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = '**Here is new member**', colour = discord.Color.green() )
    channel = self.bot.get_channel( config.CHANNEL_ID )

    with open('roles.json', 'r') as f:
        roles = json.load(f)

    role = roles[str(member.guild.id)]

    await member.add_roles( role )

    emb.set_author( name = self.bot.user )
    emb.add_field( name = "**Say Hello to**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.mention ), inline=False )
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = self.bot.user.avatar_url )
    emb.add_field( name = "**Roles is**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.roles ).replace( '[' , '' ).replace( ']' , '' ).replace( '<' , '' ).replace( '>' , '' ).replace( "'" , '' ).replace( 'Role' , '' ).replace( 'id=' , '' ).replace( 'name=' , '' ).replace( '1' , '' ).replace( '2' , '' ).replace( '3' , '' ).replace( '4' , '' ).replace( '5' , '' ).replace( '6' , '' ).replace( '7' , '' ).replace( '8' , '' ).replace( '9' , '' ).replace( '0' , '' ).replace('"', '').replace("ud", ''), inline=False )

    await channel.send( embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Auto role
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join( self, member ):
    emb = discord.Embed( title = '**Here is new member**', colour = discord.Color.green() )
    with open('messagech.json', 'r') as f:
        messagechs = json.load(f)

    messagech = messagechs[str(member.guild.id)]

    channel = self.bot.get_channel( int(messagech) )

    with open('roles.json', 'r') as f:
        roles = json.load(f)

    role = roles[str(member.guild.id)]

    role = int(role)

    role = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, id = role )

    await member.add_roles( role  )

    with open('roles.json', 'w') as f:
        json.dump(roles, f, indent=4)

    emb.set_author( name = self.bot.user )
    emb.add_field( name = "**Say Hello to**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.mention ), inline=False )
    emb.set_thumbnail( url = self.bot.user.avatar_url )
    emb.add_field( name = "**Roles is**", value = '**{}**'.format( member.roles ).replace( '[' , '' ).replace( ']' , '' ).replace( '<' , '' ).replace( '>' , '' ).replace( "'" , '' ).replace( 'Role' , '' ).replace( 'id=' , '' ).replace( 'name=' , '' ).replace( '1' , '' ).replace( '2' , '' ).replace( '3' , '' ).replace( '4' , '' ).replace( '5' , '' ).replace( '6' , '' ).replace( '7' , '' ).replace( '8' , '' ).replace( '9' , '' ).replace( '0' , '' ).replace('"', '').replace("ud", ''), inline=False )

    await channel.send( embed = emb)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `on_member_join` method is called with a `discord.Member` object called `member`.

That `member` object has a `guild` attribute, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member.guild

the `guild` object is from class `discord.Guild`
That `guild` object has an attribute called `id` which is an Integer, see https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Guild.id

So to answer the question: How to get guild id you do

```
gid = member.guild.id
```

---

Your logic for getting a `discord.Role` object is wrong. Also you don't need the guild id to get the roles. You need the guild object.

```
roles = member.guild.roles
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Guild.roles
These are all the roles the guild has.

```
role = member.guild.get_role(123456)
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Guild.get_role
This gives you the role with the given role ID.

Try to read and apply the docs. Blind programming, following tutorials or looking at other people's work won't get you far. It's nice to get the project running but at the end the docs will have all the knowledge you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the guild id from the `member` object.
`gid = member.guild.id`

Comment: you could get it for joined guild, but I don't know about present